# How to power up and boot custom industrial PC

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer, windows-ce

Someone gave me an industrial PC that was going to be thrown out at work. Unfortunately, they couldn't provide any additional information about the model and specs. I have googled all of the part numbers I could find on the labels, but couldn't find any matching results.

I wanted to try to boot the thing up, but unfortunately it looks like it is using a proprietary power connector. I did manage to probe it with a multimeter, and it seems like all of the pins (except for one) connect to GND on the top row, and to +12 V (except for the two left ones) on the bottom row. I did try to apply 12 V to these pins, but it only drew a couple of mA and was not giving any signs of life.

Power connector:

[image: Power connector]

If anyone knows a bit more about these kinds of IPCs, and how to power them and boot them up, I'm all ears :)

Part numbers:

- EBC-AC14
- EBC-AC14M5F-S6A1E
- 2660021145284 A
- TPAA675966

Some more pictures that include the part numbers and other connectors:

Part numbers:

[image: Part numbers]

Connectors on the back:

[image: Connectors on the back]

Connectors on the front:

[image: Connectors on the front]

PCB:

[image: PCB]

PCB backside:

[image: PCB backside]

Comment: any model numbers on the motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a desktop computer, but an
[Industrial PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_PC),
used to control machinery.

The device itself is the
[Advantech EBC-AC14 BOXED IPC LOW-END CPC-1.1 EBC-AC14M5F-S6A1E](http://www.yshp.net/goods-9586-Advantech+EBC-AC14+BOXED+IPC+LOW-END+CPC-11+EBC-AC14M5F-S6A1E.html),
made in China, or more precisely in Shanghai.
A Mr. Yang is given as the contact to call, if you're interested.

Since you are not in China, probably it was used with some electrical transformer.
As this wasn't given to you, I can't help with finding one.

However, it is highly unlikely that you could use it as a desktop computer.
Its specs are probably just enough to run one specific control program.

Comment: That's indeed the exact model! Thanks for your answer! I was not really planning on using it as a desktop computer, but more along the lines of what for instance a Raspberry Pi would be used for.
Unfortunately, the site you linked to doesn't give any addiotional details on the specs or connectors used, but I'll contact them to ask if they can provide some more info.